# About ODBC connection from access db to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, azure-sql-database

[image]

Hi,
I am trying to connect Azure sql database from Access database . However its giving me the following error.

When I try with the same credential from SSMS its connects perfect however, can't connect through ODBC.

Can anyone had the same experience or anyone has any input to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post connection setup from both ODBC Admin and SSMS (without authentication info of course)

Comment: Try once more. Sometimes Azure SQL first must "wake up" ...

Comment: I have used exactly the same like the link except last slide where connection failed. http://fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/cloud/link-to-azure-sql-database.html     Did many times.. but still no luck! I am sure there is something i have missed but not too knowledgeable on ODBC part.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [ODBC driver 17 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567). You need to restart computer after installing the driver or the connection won't work. Create a Machine ODBC DSN using this driver.

[image]

Provide now the Azure SQL server name:

[image]

Use SQL authentication.

[image]

On the next screen specify the database name (catalog).

Make sure you set Encrypt=True

Comment: I did exactly the same way you showed. Still its not working..

Comment: @KRMNDev Please put "Encrypt=True"

Comment: Are you using *exactly* the same login in SSMS? Have you whitelisted your IP address in Azure?